# ¿Por qué no me redirecciona a la siguiente ruta?

Tags: python, imagen, variables, flask

Estoy usando Flask con Python y html. Mi código es el siguiente:

piece.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "base_template.html" %}

{% block title %}Quarantine Chess{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<body>
  <div class="centrado">
    {% if form.color=="white" %}
      <input type="image" href="{{ url_for('to_game', color='white', piece='Pawn') }}" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Chess_plt45.svg">
      <input type="image" href="{{ url_for('to_game', color='white', piece='Rook') }}" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Chess_rlt45.svg">
</div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

ruta de 'run.py':

```
@app.route("/lobby/w", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def lobby_w():
    form=LobbyForm()
    form.color = 'white'
    return render_template("piece.html", form=form)
```

y

```
@app.route("/<string:piece>/<string:color>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def to_game():
    print piece, color
    return redirect(url_for('in_game'))
```

Lo que quiero es sin bajar nada a ningún archivo poder pasar esas variables a Python. Lo intento por medio de la url, pero no me redirecciona.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: el html lo cierro al final, en eso no hay error.

Comment: Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente?

Comment: Perdón no terminé de explicarme correctamente: querría poder extraer información del html para manejarla en python con flask, sin usar FlaskForm. Usando GET o POST. Ahora actualizo lo que tengo actualmente.

Comment: quiero manejar el value del input que al que se le de click.

Comment: algo como request.form['el value']

Comment: No puedes tener dos id con el mismo nombre, porque no se pueden separar, quizá podrías nombrar el id con diferente nombre y pasar el id como parámetro en la función también, o hacerlo con algún listener

Comment: está muy bien lo que dijiste, ahora lo cambio, pero ¿cómo llamo al valor que es modificado en el js desde python?

Comment: por el momento probé con request.args.get(), y los de POST y ambas, pero nada me funciona, asi que ahora estoy probando con pasarlo a través de la url, pero aún asi no me redirecciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estaba cerrando bien los input:
el código sin errores:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "base_template.html" %}

{% block title %}Quarantine Chess{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="centrado">
    {% if form.color=="white" %}
      <a href="{{ url_for('to_game', piece='Pawn', color='white') }}">
        <input type="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Chess_plt45.svg"/>
      </a>
      <a href="{{ url_for('to_game', piece='Rook', color='white') }}">
        <input type="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Chess_plt45.svg"/>
      </a>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

python:

```
@app.route("/lobby/b", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def lobby_b():
    form=LobbyForm()
    form.color = 'black'   
    return render_template("piece.html", form=form)

@app.route("/<string:piece>/<string:color>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def to_game(piece, color):
    print piece, color
    return redirect(url_for('in_game'))
```

Lo que no responde a la primer pregunta la cual era: cómo hacerlo por POST y/o GET mediante Flask...